# Dispatch is not a function - React Testing Library with React Redux Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-testing-library

I want to test if the component is dispatching an action to the store, for this, i have to mock the functionalities of React Hooks.

I'm using the useDispatch hook to get the dispatcher function and put inside a variable so them i can call it.

When i run my test suits, even if the useDispatch function is mocked, it returns an error saying that it's not a function.

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn(),
  useDispatch: jest.fn(() => {}),
}));

it('should be able open modal', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Dropdown />);

  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('dropdown'));
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button-Transactions'));

  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  useDispatch.mockReturnValue(dispatch);

  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(openModal('transactions'));
});
```

The error:

```
    TypeError: dispatch is not a function

      19 | 
      20 |     if (item.action) {
    > 21 |       dispatch(item.action);
         |       ^
      22 |     }
      23 | 
      24 |     return item;
```

My component:

```
const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleNavigation(item) {
    if (item.path) return history.push(item.path);

    if (item.action) {
      dispatch(item.action);
    }

    return item;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component was trying to execute a function that wasn't declared yet.
We need to mock before of the render method

```
const dispatch = jest.fn();
useDispatch.mockReturnValue(jest.fn());

const dropdown = render(<Dropdown />);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you mocked it, you haven't specified a value.

I thought of two ways to do this:

1. Having a real store in your test, so you can test the integration:

```
const mockedStore = { /* the things you need in store in your test */ };
const store = configureStore(mockedStore, browserHistory);

const { getByTestId } = render(<Provider store={store}><Dropdown /></Provider>);
```

2. Mock your `dispatch`, but you ll end up having infinite issues with `useSelector` (especially if you have more than one useSelector in the tree you rendered).

```
import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux';

// useDispatch returns a function which we are mocking here
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

beforeAll(() => {
  ReactRedux.useDispatch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockDispatch);
});

beforeEach(() => {
  ReactRedux.useDispatch.mockClear();
});


expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(yourAction);
```

Please note that the real issue you will face is not with dispatch, but with `useSelector`.
If you mock it, it will return the value you want. But what if you have more than one in your tree ? for that, I real store is necessary as far as I know.

Comment: But since i'm calling jest.mock in the first lines and passing an factory with mocks, am i not specifying the values?

Comment: You mocked useDispatch to return nothing, it has to return a function that will be called as a dispatch. (second option in my answer)

Comment: It turns out that i need to mock the functionality of useDispatch before rendering the component

Comment: Exactly! but there are more problems you will face if you keep doing this!